# The Google map property always shows up undefined in Angular 16 (@angular/google-maps package)

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps

The following is the code snippet for the google map wrapper HTML and TS file for which I got the desired output in Angular 12, but when I installed the same wrapper in the latest Angular to get the same output, I am unable to access this.map property as it always shows up undefined. Am I missing something here? or does this wrapper @angular/google-maps not support the latest version of Angular yet? (I have already installed npm package for @types/google.maps and the wrapper, also inserted API key into my index.html file.

My requirement here is pretty simple. I just want to have a zoomable draggable map wrapper with a marker at the center whose position should be saved as coordinates when I click on a save button in HTML.

> index.html

```
<script id="map" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXXX&language=en"></script>
```

> HTML File google map component

```
               <div class="map-section">
                    <google-map 
                    #map
                    (mapDrag)="trackCoordinates()"
                      [options]="options"
                      (zoomChanged)="trackCoordinates()"
                      height="100%"
                      width="100%"
                      [zoom]="zoom"
                      [center]="center"
                    >
                      <map-info-window #infoWindow>{{ infoWindowMessage }}</map-info-window>
                      <map-marker
                        #markerElem="mapMarker"
                        [position]="markerPosition"
                      ></map-marker>
                    </google-map>
                  </div>
                  <div class="flex justify-between items-center mt-5">
                    <div class="f-r">
                      <ng-container *ngIf="!!coordinates">
                        <span class="text-secondary-text"> Selected Location:</span> <br />
                        <span
                          class="text-neutral f-m"
                          >{{currentLocation?.["formatted_address"]}}</span
                        ><br />
                        <span class="text-neutral f-m"
                          >Latitude: {{ coordinates?.lat }}, Longitude:{{
                            coordinates?.lng
                          }}</span
                        >
                      </ng-container>
                      <ng-container *ngIf="!confirmedCoordinates">
                        <!-- Navigate to the target location and click the marker to confirm location -->
                      </ng-container>
                    </div>
                    <button (click)="saveMapLocation()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
                      Confirm Location
                    </button>
                    <!-- <button *ngIf="!!confirmedCoordinates" (click)="resetSavedMapLocation()" type="button" class="btn   btn-secondary mx-3 text-white">Reset Selected Location</button> -->
                  </div>
                <!--end::Input group-->
            </div>
```

> TS file for google maps component

```
zoom = 18;
      placeId = "";
      center: google.maps.LatLngLiteral | google.maps.LatLng;
      options: google.maps.MapOptions = {
        mapTypeId: 'hybrid',
        zoomControl: true,
        scrollwheel: true,
        disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
        minZoom: 16,
        gestureHandling: 'greedy',
      };
      markerPosition: any;
      coordinates: any;
      mapBounds: any;
      showMap: boolean = false;
      infoWindowMessage: any;
      confirmedCoordinates: any;
      currentLocation: any;
      marker: MapMarker;
      @ViewChild(MapInfoWindow, { static: false }) infoWindow: MapInfoWindow;
      @ViewChild(GoogleMap, { static: false }) map: GoogleMap


  
  trackCoordinates() { //event listener for map drag to get coordinates and adjust marker position
    console.info(this.map) //always undefined 
      this.infoWindowMessage="Navigate to the target location and click to select coordinates"
    this.coordinates =     {  lat: parseFloat("23.6167"),
    lng: parseFloat("58.5667")}
    let geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    let latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(
      parseFloat(this.coordinates?.lat),
      parseFloat(this.coordinates?.lng)
    );
}


  saveMapLocation() {
    if (!!this.coordinates) {
      this.confirmedCoordinates = this.coordinates;
      this.center = {
        lat: parseFloat(this.confirmedCoordinates?.lat),
        lng: parseFloat(this.confirmedCoordinates?.lng),
      };
    }
  }

  resetSavedMapLocation() {
    this.confirmedCoordinates = null;
  }
```

Comment: with static false it wouldn't be available before ngAfterViewInit are meaning if you executing `trackCoordinates` before that i would be undefined. You can make it static: true to reach it ngOnInit, but then you component can't have a structural directive wrapping it.